# Minecraft in split screen without having a live account?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

Is it possible to play minecraft in split screen without an Xbox live account?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can play on split screen according to: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Splitscreen

If you have another controller turned on it should pop up on screen saying "Press start to join game"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can play local splitscreen with local accounts.

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Splitscreen

Answer (score 0):

Not really known in my family but it IS supposed to be possible without an Xbox Live account.  Though when I tried it it didn't say to press start to join the game.  But it IS possible.